# Every _______ $d$-manifold has an $S$-structure

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, manifolds

I am looking for some analogous nontrivial but known statements and references about statements of the form:

> Every _______ $d$-manifold has an $S$-structure.

Here _______ is a placeholder for certain conditions, like **orientability, complex, triangulable, PL, topological**, etc.

This is very vague. What do I really mean?

For example:

1. [Every orientable $4$-manifold has a $\mathit{Spin}^c$ Structure](https://mathoverflow.net/q/266946/27004) is true.

The precise statement on J. W. Morgan's "The Seiberg-Witten Equations and Applications to the Topology of Smooth Four-Manifolds (MN-44)" that a $4$-manifold $X$ admits a $\mathit{Spin}^c$ structure (Lemma 3.1.2) seems to be that [every *orientable* $4$-manifold $X$ admits a $\mathit{Spin}^c$ structure](https://mathoverflow.net/q/266946/27004). This means that we impose the $w_1(X)=0$ for the *orientable* $4$-manifold $X$. Note that

$$Spin^c=\frac{(Spin \times U(1))}{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}.$$

2. [Every nonorientable $4$-manifold has a $\mathit{Pin^c}$, $\mathit{Pin^{\tilde c+}}$ or $\mathit{Pin^{\tilde c-}}$ structure](https://mathoverflow.net/q/310373/27004) is false.

Note that 
$$\mathit{Pin^c}=\frac{(\mathit{Pin}^+ \times U(1))}{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}=\frac{(Pin^- \times U(1))}{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}},$$ 
$$\mathit{Pin}^{\tilde c+}=\frac{(\mathit{Pin}^+ \ltimes U(1))}{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}},$$ 
$$\mathit{Pin}^{\tilde c-}=\frac{(\mathit{Pin}^- \ltimes U(1))}{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}.$$

3. [Spin-H structures](https://mathoverflow.net/q/304471/27004)

$$\mathit{Spin}^H (n)=\mathit{Spin}(n) \times \mathrm{SU}(2)/{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}=\mathit{Spin}(n) \times \mathrm{SU}(2)/\{ 1,-1\}$$

> Do we have similar statements analogous to every _______ $d$-manifold has a $\mathit{Spin}^H$ structure? Such as every orientable $d$-manifold has a $\mathit{Spin}^H$ structure for some $d$? (like $d=5$?)

4. Are there other similar statements?

Comment: All the examples you gave are examples of [$G$-structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-structure_on_a_manifold), so maybe using '$G$-structure' instead of '$S$-structure' would be a more informative title. Unless you're interested in a broader question.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese isn't your replacement for "..." overly emphatic? I hesitated to change into simply "(...)"; I agree I was puzzled by "..." but I'm skeptical about forged math mode.

Comment: @YCor: I just replaced the Latex command with ______. Do you feel it is still an issue? I was just trying to clarify the existence of a placeholder.

Comment: Actually in the title I'd even suggest to even replace it with words, but maybe it's better if the OP does it. The long underscore catches the eye a bit too much in the front list (to my taste).

Comment: Every orientable 2-manifolds admits a  spin structure and a complex structure. I think, both statements are well-known but non-trivial. For example, to prove the existence of a spin structure one should use Gauss-Bonnet.

Comment: @Sebastian: I don't know how Gauss-Bonnet can be used to prove that. More generally, any orientable three-manifold admits a spin structure. Similarly, any closed three-manifold admits a pin$^-$ structure.

Comment: In dimension 2, the spin covering is the twofold covering $S^1\to S^1=SO(2).$  A necessary and sufficient condition that the $SO(2)$ frame bundle of the surface  admits a spin covering is that the degree of the associated complex line bundle (with respect to the standard representation of $S^1$ on $\mathbb C$) is even, which follows from Gauss-Bonnet. I do not know whether there are more direct proofs.

Comment: Use the Euler characteristic: it's even.

Answer (score 8):

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.04934), Aleksandar Milivojevic and I prove that every orientable manifold of dimension $\leq 7$ is spin$^h$. We also construct, for every $d \geq 8$, infinitely many homotopy types of closed, simply connected $d$-manifolds which are not spin$^h$.

There are several statements of the form you seek:

- Every manifold of dimension $d \leq 2$ is pin$^-$. In addition, every compact $3$-manifold is pin$^-$. I don't know if there is a non-compact 3-manifold which is not pin$^-$.
- Every orientable manifold of dimension $d \leq 3$ is spin, and the orientable four-dimensional manifold $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is not spin. Note that for orientable manifolds, the spin, pin$^+$, and pin$^-$ conditions are equivalent, so one can make the same statements for orientable pin$^+$ manifolds or orientable pin$^-$ manifolds.
- Every orientable manifold of dimension $d \leq 4$ is spin$^c$, and the Wu manifold $SU(3)/SO(3)$ is an orientable five-manifold which is not spin$^c$. The proof you refer to only works for the closed case, for the general case, see [this note](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eteichner/Papers/spin.pdf) by Teichner and Vogt.
- Every orientable 2-manifold is complex, while $S^4$ is an orientable 4-manifold which is not complex.
- Every orientable manifold of dimension $d \leq 4$ is stably almost complex, and the Wu manifold $SU(3)/SO(3)$ is an orientable five-manifold which is not stably almost complex.

The third and fifth statements are very similar. This is due to the fact that every stably almost complex manifold is spin$^c$.